# Generic C# BST tree, choosing type

Tags: c#, generics, types, binary-search-tree

So I created a generic BST in C#, I've tested and it works well. I want to finish off the program asking the user to enter a type of the tree they'd like to use, then it will create a tree of that type using my generic tree, ask them for inputs for it, and display info about it. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case "bool":
                functionToCreateBST(userChoice);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Input did not match any given type!");
                break;
        }
```

The function will contain some code along these lines:

```
BSTtree<userChoice> test = new BSTtree<userChoice>();
```

How can I do this? I'm going to have about 14 switch cases listed with different types. I want to call a function from each of the switch cases, passing in the given type. Then the function will have all the code to create the BST, take inputs for it, and display info about it, and use the given type in the process.

The code for my function is about 40 lines, I obviously just want to have 1 function to do this, that will change depending on the type, instead of copy and paste 40 lines for 14 different cases!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a generic function using the selected type.  Something like

```
void functionToCreateBST<T>()
{
   BSTtree<T> test = new BSTtree<T>();
   // ...
}


switch(userChoice)
{
   case "bool":
      functionToCreateBST<bool>(userChoice);
      break;
   default:
      Console.WriteLine("Input did not match any given type!");
      break;    
}
```

Comment: Great, I'm still getting used to generics...simple fix I guess. Thanks! If you know, do you know why I HAD to implement Icomparible for my function? I thought I only needed to do that if I was going to be comparing my type T in the function with CompareTo, for example.

Comment: Sorry, for that I would need to see your code, the message your were getting, and on what line.